Complex analysis: on conformal maps
We have collection of all maps from unit disk to upper half plane define $H=\{|T'(0)|: \text{T is conformal and}~ T(0)=\frac{i}{2}\} $
Now we want to find $sup~H~$
We have mobius transformation $$T(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
By applying $T(0)=\frac{i}{2}$ and finding derivative at 0 we get $T'(0)=\frac{2a-i}{2d}$. Now I have no idea to proceed further any hints??

One such Mobius transformations is $$\Phi(z) = \frac i2 \frac{1+z}{1-z}.$$
One checks that $\Phi'(0)=i.$ Then apply the Schwarz lemma to all possible functions of the form $\Phi^{-1} \circ T.$ The result is that $|T'(0)| \le 1.$ The maximum is attained at $\Phi.$ In general the maximum is attained precisely at the functions $$T(z) = \frac i2 \frac{1+az}{1-az}$$
where $|a| = 1.$

is there explicit formula for getting mobius maps from disk to upper/half planes

The easiest way is to construct the inverse map first. In this case it should map $\frac i2 \mapsto 0$ and the conjugate of  $\frac i2$ with respect to the real line to the inversion of $0$ with respect to the circle. That is $-\frac i2\mapsto\infty.$ You get $$\frac{z-\frac{i}{2}}{z+\frac{i}{2}} = \frac{2z-i}{2z+i}.$$ Finally invert it as if it were a matrix.
